# Need an EMail with HTML table using filtered google sheet data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

I need to send an email to the recipients based on certain criteria. I have done this code about 200 mails received. Loop is not been ending and the filtering function also didn't work. The complete table has been received. Kindly help me with this.

The data [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cxq2lxNqMFR8hpIwW4qmpjBYve2FakVtSarb7hqGRVE/edit#gid=0) has also been attached:

```js
    function createTable(data){ 
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      function create_filter(){
        const  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Filter_Sheet");
        const  range = sheet1.getRange("A2:AH");
        const  filter = range.createFilter();
        const Filter_Criteria1 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThan(2);
        const  Filter_Criteria2 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(["Report Pending"]||["Site Visit Pending"]||["Query Raised"]||["Hold"]);
        const coll1 = 24;
        const coll2 = 10;
        
        const  add_filter1 =  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(coll1,Filter_Criteria1);
        const  add_filter2 = filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(coll2,Filter_Criteria2);}
      
      //To be looped in the future, 10 in range to be replaced with k
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:AH");
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
    
      //Table Header
      var table = "<html><body><br><table border=1><tr><th>Compliance Score</th><th>STSOR Value</th><th>STSOR %</th><th>ZZ lines</th><th>ZZ%</th><th>PI lines Counted</th><th>PI %</th><th>NRDS Value</th><th>NRDS %</tr></br>";
    
      //table Body
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        cells = data[i]; //puts each cell in an array position
        table = table + "<tr>";
    
          for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++){
              table = table + "<td>"+ cells[u] +"</td>";
          }
        table = table + "</tr>"
        
    
      //Send the email:
     MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "rama.mannava465@gmail.com", 
        subject: "Example",
        htmlBody: table}); 
         }
    }
```

Comment: do not use multiple times same function name as createTable!

Comment: put MailApp.sendEmail ourside the loop (i), it is included in the loop in your script. Indend correctly to see it.

Comment: Thank you can you please help me in updated code. Please

Comment: you need to remove duplicated functions and move MailApp.sendEmail outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function createTable() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const dataRange = sheet1.getRange("A2:AH");

  var criterias = ["Report Pending", "Site Visit Pending", "Query Raised"]
  var backgrounds = dataRange.getBackgrounds(); // Added
  var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues(); // Modified
  var table = "<html><body><br><table border=1><tr><th>Compliance Score</th><th>STSOR Value</th><th>STSOR %</th><th>ZZ lines</th><th>ZZ%</th><th>PI lines Counted</th><th>PI %</th><th>NRDS Value</th><th>NRDS %</tr></br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cells = data[i];
    if (cells[23] > 2 && criterias.indexOf(cells[9]) != -1) {
      table = table + "<tr>";
      for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++) {
        table = table + `<td style="background-color:${backgrounds[i][u]}">` + cells[u] + "</td>"; // Modified
      }
      table = table + "</tr>"
    }
  }

  //Send the email:
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "ramauni3994@gmail.com",
    subject: "Example",
    htmlBody: table
  });
}
```